# RDoc : Change name of 'Atttributes:' section in ri-documentation

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, rdoc, ri

I'm using some meta-programming to generate a bunch of methods in ruby like so:

```
class EmotionalObject
  def self.mood( name, *details )
    define_method(name) do
      # ...
    end
  end

  mood :happy, #...
  mood :sad, #...
  mood :ebuillent, #...
  #...
 end
```

I know that I can pass `rdoc` '-A mood' to get it to recognize my mood
generation code as attributes, which is handy, since then they at least
get recognized.

However, they're really more like regular methods than attributes, so
I don't want them listed under the 'Attributes:' section when I look
at the documentation using `ri`.  I don't have any regular attributes,
so is there any simple way I can just change the title of this section to be 'Moods:'
or something like that, so my users are at least curious enough to type `ri EmotionalObject#happy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hardcoded into the RDoc templates, but you can make a new template to use by duplicating the default "html" template and changing the heading name by hand.

See the RDoc template source here: http://github.com/juretta/ruby/blob/master/lib/rdoc/generator/html/html.rb#L601.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that somewhere around rdoc 2.4.1 they removed `--accessor` and replaced it with using `##` comments on each meta-method.  While this allows you to get them out of the attributes section, it also forces you to comment each one individually.

http://rdoc.rubyforge.org/RDoc/Parser/Ruby.html